# For MacOS: how to bind left and right option keys separately?

Tags: key-bindings, osx

Using Gnu Emacs in MacOS "El Capitan".

Question:

How do I bind the *right* option key to control but keep the *left* option key bound to option?

Background:

I found that even with caps_lock as control my left hand would start to ache, so I decided to have as many control keys as possible.  Before switching to Mac I never used caps_lock or option (still don't use caps_lock), so I bound both of them to control: caps_lock to control in the Keyboard systems preferences and option to control in my .emacs file.

Unlike PC keyboards, the Apple keyboard has only one control key but *two* option keys (one on the outside of each of the two command keys):

[image]

But now I'm finding that I would like to be able to have an option key in Emacs.  There is already a control key on the bottom left but not one on the bottom right, so ideally I would revert just the left option key (now mapped to control) back to option But I still want the right option key to be a control.

These are the relevant lines from my .emacs file.

```
(setq 
  mac-option-key-is-control t
  mac-option-modifier 'control
 )
```

Comment: If you need any special symbols or type in a foreign language somtimes, you may wish to keep the right option key available for OSX default behavior:  `(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)` and set the `ns-right-command-modifier` to whatever you want -- e.g., `'control`.

Comment: Also: some versions of Emacs for OS X use `mac-right-option-modifier` instead of `ns-right-option-modifier`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there.

By default, the `ns-XXXXX-modifier` variables affect both the
left and right versions of the key.  However, you can change the
*right* one with `ns-right-XXXXX-modifier`.

So: to set the left one to `A` and the right one to `B`, you can
set the `ns-XXXXX-modifier` to `A` and `ns-right-XXXXX-modifier`
to `B`.

The following example sets the left option modifier to meta, and
the right one to control:

```
(setq ns-option-modifier      'meta
      ns-right-option-modifer 'control)
```

See https://emacsformacosx.com/tips ("Changing the Modifier
Keys") for more details.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!  Now since I want to keep left option as option and change just right option to control, I just need to do (setq ns-right-option-modifer 'control).  But I still don't know what "ns" means.  I have "mac" instead of "ns" in my other setq commands.

Comment: @Ruby: the `ns`, I believe, refers to the [NeXTSTEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP) operating system that became the source for OSX after Apple bought it.  My best guess is that you can use the `ns` and `mac` prefixes interchangeably on these variables, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Indeed, the `mac-` version is just an alias for the `ns-` version of these symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Replying to Dan's answer:

The behavior of the mentioned variables have changed (at least in Spacemacs): `ns-right-option-modifer` triggers `ns-option-modifier` as well - which makes no sense if you ask me - but if you set:

`ns-option-modifier` to meta

and

`ns-right-option-modifer` to control (just for this example)

pressing just the **right option key** will result in "C-M-x" instead of "C-x".

The solution is to switch the keys and use left option key for accented characters.

Check the details here:
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10499

Solution:

```
(setq ns-option-modifier 'none
      ns-right-alternate-modifier 'meta)
```

Further comments:

```
(defvaralias 'mac-allow-anti-aliasing 'ns-antialias-text)
(defvaralias 'mac-command-modifier 'ns-command-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-right-command-modifier 'ns-right-command-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-control-modifier 'ns-control-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-right-control-modifier 'ns-right-control-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-option-modifier 'ns-option-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-right-option-modifier 'ns-right-option-modifier)
(defvaralias 'mac-function-modifier 'ns-function-modifier)

(defvaralias 'ns-option-modifier 'ns-alternate-modifier)
(defvaralias 'ns-right-option-modifier 'ns-right-alternate-modifier)
```

Emacs version:                                                0.200.13@27.0.50 (spacemacs-base)

Answer (score 1):

emacs on osx has a few `ns-*-modifier` variables that help for this particular case.

in general, you can use karabiner (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap keys under osx.